# Como utilizar a classe UrlFetchApp com node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando utilizar uma classe do Google Apps Script, porém estou com dificuldades em encontrar informações de como utilizar as classes contidas no Apps Scripts e executar no node.

Ex: conversor.js

```
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
    console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME');
    process.exit(1);
}
// Read the file and print its contents.
var objects;
var fs = require('fs')
, filename = process.argv[2];

function print(item, index){
    var sourceLang = 'auto';
    var targetLang = 'pt';

    var sourceText = 'Traduzir';

    //var translatedText = LanguageApp.translate(item.mappings.default.default, sourceLang, targetLang);
    //console.log(translatedText);

    var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" 
    + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);

    var result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());

    translatedText = result[0][0][0];
    console.log(translatedText);
    // console.log(item.mappings.default.default);
    // console.log(item.mappings.default.short);
}

fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
  //console.log('OK: ' + filename);
  objects = JSON.parse(data);

  objects.forEach(print);

  console.log(objects.length);
  //console.log(data);
});
```

Quando executo com o comando :

```
node conversor.js math_digits.json
```

Resultado :

```
/home/alcance/Área de Trabalho/conversor/conversor.js:23
    var result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
                            ^

ReferenceError: UrlFetchApp is not defined
    at print (/home/alcance/Área de Trabalho/conversor/conversor.js:23:26)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /home/alcance/Área de Trabalho/conversor/conversor.js:36:11
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

Bom descrito o problema, gostaria de saber se alguém sebe como eu faço esse script funcionar, ou que me indique outra classe que possa realizar a mesma coisa que a UrlFetchApp neste contexto, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Onde você importa o `UrlFetchApp`? O erro já diz tudo, você está tentando acessar algo que não existe. Se está importada no projeto, você provavelmente precisará usar `require`, `import` ou instanciar esse cara.

Comment: Sim, mas eu não sei o namespace do require, "require("?")", não encontrei nenhum exemplo, e também não sei o que tenho que instalar pelo npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método que você está procurando ([UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)) faz parte do [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). A descrição diz:

> Increase the power of your favorite Google apps — like Calendar, Docs, Drive, Gmail, and Sheets.
>   Apps Script lets you do more with Google. All on a JavaScript platform in the cloud.

Atenção para o ponto: *All on a Javascript platform in the cloud*. Isso significa que todo o código escrito nessa *suite* deve **obrigatoriamente** rodar na plataforma do Google na nuvem. Eles, inclusive, tem até um formato de arquivo diferente para os seus scripts (`.gs`, [veja um exemplo aqui](https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/blob/master/simple_tasks/Code.gs)).

Essa plataforma tem um lugar específico pra rodar os *scripts*, que é o [Google Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/). Você pode ver na descrição que eles dizem, novamente, que esses *scripts* rodam na plataforma deles na nuvem, e que tudo que você precisa é do *browser*.

Isso significa, pelo menos pra mim, que o que você está tentando fazer é impossível. Não existe em lugar nenhum da descrição do GAS referências à conexões com o Node ou com qualquer outra coisa. O que existe são [Standalone scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) que existem sem vínculo à qualquer um dos *apps* do Google, mas, de qualquer maneira, estão "hospedados" no seu GDrive.

Existe também um pacote no NPM chamado [Node Google Apps Script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-google-apps-script), mas ele apenas permite o uso do seu editor de escolha para escrever o seu código.

Em resumo, parece-me que você está tentando fazer algo que não é possível. Sugiro rever a sua fonte ou exemplificar melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Parece mesmo não ser possível, obrigado pela ajuda.